# Showing a simple example of uniform convergence in probability

Tags: probability-theory, uniform-convergence

Let $\{y_1,\dots,y_n\}$ a random sample. Let

$f_n(\mu) = \frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n (y_i - \mu)^2, \quad f(\mu) = E[(y_i - \mu)^2].$

Let $\Theta \subset \mathbb{R}$ be a compact set. I want to show that

$\sup_{\mu \in \Theta} |f_n(\mu) - f(\mu)| \to^p 0$

I know that since $f$ and $f_n$ are continuous for all $n$ the $\sup$ exists and is attained in $\Theta$. But I am not sure how to proceed further and show convergence in probability for that object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since $f_n$ and $f$ have a particular expression, we can try to simplify $f_n(\mu)-f(\mu)$ as much as possible, that is,
\begin{align}
f_n(\mu)-f(\mu)&=\frac 1n\sum_{i=1}^n \left(\left(y_i-\mu\right)^2-\mathbb E\left[\left(y_i-\mu\right)^2\right]\right)\\
&=\frac 1n\sum_{i=1}^n \left(y_i^2-2\mu y_i+\mu^2-\mathbb E\left[ y_i^2 \right]+2\mu\mathbb E\left[y_i\right]-\mu^2\right)\\
&=\frac 1n\sum_{i=1}^n\left(y_i^2-\mathbb E\left[y_i^2\right]\right)
-2\mu\frac 1n\sum_{i=1}^n\left(y_i -\mathbb E\left[y_i\right]\right)
\end{align}
hence
$$
\sup_{\mu \in \Theta} |f_n(\mu) - f(\mu)|\leqslant \left\lvert \frac 1n\sum_{i=1}^n\left(y_i^2-\mathbb E\left[y_i^2\right]\right)\right\rvert+
2\sup_{\mu\in\Theta}\lvert \mu\rvert\left\lvert \frac 1n\sum_{i=1}^n\left(y_i-\mathbb E\left[y_i\right]\right)\right\rvert .
$$
Both terms converge in probability to zero by the weak law of large numbers.

Comment: Great! Can you be more specific about the direct application of the WLLN? These two terms are absolute values of sample averages rather than just sample averages.

Comment: Both terms go to $0$ in probability (since you have sample average minus the mean).

Comment: Sure. But you are just saying that since that is the case, it should also be the case for the absolute value of that difference, correct?

Comment: Yes, if $Z_n\to 0$ in probability, then $\lvert Z_n\rvert\to 0$ so indeed, the difference in absolute values goes to $0$.